# Page navigation with parameters jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, navigation

I am learning jQuery Mobile right now, but I have a problem. When I am navigating between pages I want to pass some data between this pages. But I can't fix this, this is what I created to test it, but it's not working. I already searched some fora and Google, but can't find an working answer.

Do anyone of you know a solution for this?

Page 1;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Test.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Vertegenwoordigers.Page1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<div data-role="page" id="Page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a id="ToPage2" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="arrow-r">Page 2</a>  
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        Page 1
    </div>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

Page 2:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Test.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Vertegenwoordigers.Page2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <div data-role="page" id="Page2">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a id="ToPage1" href="/Page1.aspx" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">Page 1</a>    
            <h1>Page 2</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            Page 2
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () { });

$('#Page1').live('pagebeforecreate', function (event) {
console.log("Page1 pagebeforecreate");
console.log(event); });

$('#Page1').live('pagecreate', function (event) {
console.log("Page1 pagecreate");

$('#ToPage2').bind('click', function () {
    console.log("ToPage2 click");

    $.mobile.changePage("/Page2.aspx", {
        type: "post",
        data: "testdatastring"
    });

});});


$('#Page2').live('pagebeforecreate', function (event) {
console.log("Page2 pagebeforeload");
console.log(event); });

$('#Page2').live('pagecreate', function (event) {
console.log("Page2 pagecreate");
console.log(event);});
```

I hope some of you can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the answer, I need to use just a 'HREF' and the problem is gone.